# How do I allocate a slice in Rust with a slice known at runtime?

Tags: rust, slice, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have seen replies telling you to use `Vec::with_capacity(some_size);` but that feels weird.

Why do I need to use a Vector to get a slice? I do not want to grow the slice later, I just want to use a plain slice, but the size is known at runtime because it comes from some program input.

My current solution is:

```rust
   let mutable_zeroed_slice: &mut [u8] = &mut vec![0; size][..];
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic and non convoluted?

Updated: You can't use the trick before wrapped within a function as you will lose the slice reference upon return.

Update 2: As pointed out in the first reply, `Vec::with_capacity(size)[..]` will give you an immutable empty slice with the given capacity, which is not very useful.

Comment: Your "solution" doesn't compile.

Comment: yes, thanks! Just updated the text to explain.

Comment: Using `vec![0; n].into_boxed_slice()` is the idiomatic way of doing this. After optimization It's pretty much just a `calloc(n, 1)` with error checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want the growable property, but you still need the storage to be allocated.

`&[u8]` refers to some data allocated *somewhere*; the `Vec` you try to create here will disappear at the end of the function, then any slice referring to its content will be dangling, and Rust prevents you from doing that.

The idea is to use a *boxed-slice*: it is boxed in order to allocate the storage, but it is not growable (as vectors are).
An easy way to achieve this is to build a vector, then steal its content.

Note that you seem to make a confusion between [capacity](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.capacity) and [size/length](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.len).

```rust
fn new_byte_slice(size: usize) -> Box<[u8]> {
    vec![0; size].into_boxed_slice()
}

fn main() {
    let values = new_byte_slice(10);
    println!("{:?}", values);
}
/*
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Yes my code was wrong... keep forgetting the rules. The things is that worked inline, but when you move it to a function Rust does not do automatic escape. 
The box solution works but still feels a bit convoluted to me. I would expect something like:
`let slice: &[u8] = allocate_slice(5)`
This is a very basic need in most programs, most arrays you need to use will not have sizes you know beforehand. Maybe Rust avoids this need doing things differently?

Comment: There will be a [new_uninit_slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new_uninit_slice) in the future as well

Comment: Thanks! I think I better ask for what i want to do exactly, maybe the problem I want to solve requires in Rust a different strategy to what I was used to do in other languages.

Comment: The original problem is I am reading from a variable stream of bytes, basically decoding wired data into actual language types and structs. Some bits there are variable width byte arrays inside the stream.

Comment: When I find those bytes in the wire, I want to get a copy of them as a immutable slice of bytes. In Rust it must be an slice, as an array size must be known at compile time, which is not the case. Usually, in other languages, you would allocate a mutable slice and copy the bytes in it, not sure how idiomatic Rust does this.

Comment: Must ask another question for that.

Comment: Assuming you have a `&mut [u8]` of your data stream, you can simply copy it using `Box::new(*slice)`.

Comment: @user1098300 But how `let slice: &[u8] = allocate_slice(5)` could even be possible (whatever`allocate_slice()` does, except static storage)? The type `&[T]` is *non-owning*.

Comment: @prog-fh yes `&[T]` is not owning, but that is kind of a language design decision. They could have created a `Slice<T>` object instead that owns a pointer to memory, a size and maybe capacity, plus a handful of basic operations... they seem to have called that `Vec<T>` instead and loaded it with a lot of functionality out of the box that makes it feel much heavier than a simple slice.
To my taste a more basic building block would have less baggage and then you can still have a `Vec<T>` on top extending that, and filling more advanced needs.
But it is what it is.

Comment: @user1098300 This hypothetical `Slice<T>` is just spelled `Box<[T]>`. It is exactly what you want. A `Box<U>` is an owned `U` allocated on the heap; a `Box<[T]>` is an owned slice allocated on the heap, and a slice knows its size, as you expect. I guess the trouble comes from the fact that we tend to name `[T]` and `&[T]` a *slice* in both cases, which is quite ambiguous...